# How to combine pandas multiple values in one column to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe, 1st columns (A) and 2nd column (B) are given and I want the output similar to Column (C).  Once I get the output in Column (C), I will remove duplicated rows from Column (A) to have a clean out put only for Column (A) and Column (C) as shown in table 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a `groupby` statement.  `df_out = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(', '.join)`

Comment: thank you, it did work